# Error of deserializing a URLSafeTimedSerializer .loads() function

Tags: flask

[error and find for max_age variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Dj3.png)

Firstly I generate the serilizer globally with a fixed salt for debugging:

```
    # Serializer for generating confirmation tokens 
    serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.secret_key)
    salt = "dfsajHUIHHfhuiowefb3423NJADK"
```

Then I send the email in route endpoint "/signup" with a token generated by userID, and this part succeeded:

```
    # Token need to be sent
    token = serializer.dumps(userID, salt)
    print(salt)
    # Email sending part
    confirmation_link = url_for(
        'confirm',
        token=token,
        _external=True  # Generate an absolute URL
    )
```

But in my "/confirm" route, the deserialization failed, the error is "TimedSerializer.loads() got multiple values for argument 'max_age'", but I only set "max_age" inside the function.

```
`@app.route('/confirm/<token>', methods=['GET'])
def confirm(token):
    try:
        print(salt)
        # Attempt to deserialize the token back into the userID
        user_id = serializer.loads(token, salt, max_age = app.config['timer'])

    except Exception as e:
        print('The confirmation link is invalid or has expired.', 'danger')
        print(e)
        return redirect('/signup')`
```

What can I do for it?

I used a fixed salt and print the salt and token, they are consistent, and the error said the problem is the max_age variable but I did not use it in any other place. I want to confirm the email successfully.

Comment: The function signature is `loads(s, max_age=None, return_timestamp=False, salt=None)` and therefore your salt is being interpreted as max_age. Try `serializer.loads(token, salt = salt, max_age = app.config['timer'])`

Comment: That really helps! but it is really weird that my instructor's example and the website of serializer all show that salt is the second element